# Is the product of two stable asymmetric matrices also stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two square *asymmetric* matrices $A$ and $B$ that are Hurwitz stable (with maximum eigenvalue less than one), is the product $AB$ also stable?

This is clearly true when $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, since the induced norm has the property that $||AB|| \leq ||A|| ||B||$ and $||A|| = \lambda_{\max}(A)$. However, because the maximum eigenvalue is not necessarily equal to the matrix norm in the asymmetric case, I am not sure if this still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. As a counterexample, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&2\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&0\\2&0}.
$$
$A$ and $B$ each have $0$ as their only eigenvalue but $AB$ has eigenvalues $0,4$.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be true if only $A$ were symmetric and not $B$?

Comment: Nevermind, there is a counterexample with $A=[[0,0.75],[0.75,0]]$ and $B$ from your example